# settings.json 'end of file expected' error

Tags: html, json, settings

I am beginner, and while configuration of VS Code I've got an error.

```
"[html]": { 
   "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features" 
},  
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "html": {
        "inline_break": 2
    }
},
```

Error shows as underlined key "[html]".

At first the error displayed as underlined colon mark after "[html]", then it has changed although I just copied it, deleted and pasted it again.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "[dart]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.formatOnType": true,
        "editor.rulers": [
        ],
        "editor.selectionHighlight": false,
        "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
        "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
        "editor.tabCompletion": "onlySnippets",
        "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false
    }
}
```

A Sample settings.json is added. You're missing braces in the start and end.